# Using the data in 3 files containing column x I need to output the data in column account

Tags: powershell, batch-file, batch-processing

I have a 3 txt files namely file1 , file2 , file3 containing data separated with "|"
I need to filter all the lines that only having "1" in columnx and print the value in the column "account"

file1.txt

```
  line|account|column3|columnx
  line1|111111|jahadkadaldabndal|1
  line2|2323413341|adajkadadbjkqqweq|0
  line3|21122|adaieaqelqq|0
  line4|236521|jadad|1
```

file2.txt

```
  line|account|column3|columnx
  line1|1117831|jahadkadaldabndal|1
  line2|23234178841|adajkadadbjkqqweq|1
  line3|21122|adaieaqelqq|0
  line4|236526|jadad|1
```

file3.txt

```
  line|account|column3|columnx
  line1|1113333|jahadkadaldabndal|1
  line2|232341335|adajkadadbjkqqweq|1
  line3|21124|adaieaqelqq|1
  line4|236523|jadad|1
```

output should be like this :

```
 111111
 236521
 1113333
 236523
 21124
 232341335
 1117831
 23234178841
 236526
```

i have a code but online for one file txt only.

```
    powershell -nop -c "(import-csv .\*.txt -del '|'|? columnx -eq 1).account"
```

I'm still figuring out what I should use I'm really new in this stuff can anyone teach me or give me some code so that I can finish this one thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
for %%A in (*.txt) do for /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=2,4 delims=|" %%A in ("%%~A") do (
    for %%B in (%%B) do if %%B EQU 1 echo %%A
)
pause
```

`for %%A in (*.txt)` iterates through each text file. the wildcard can be set as appropriate e.g. `file*.txt` or whatever as appropriate to your case.

`for /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=2,4 delims=|"` reads each file that is passed by the parent `FOR`, process each file line by line takes tokens 2 and 4 from each line (that is account and columnx). `skip=1` skips the first line if the file contains the header `line|account|column3|columnx` if not remove `skip=1`

`for %%B in (%%B)` is to remove any leading/trailing spaces from the last token (columnx) for comparison against `1` to be correct if last the column contains spaces.

Comment: so if my columnx is 24th column ill just edit the token=2,4 to token=2,24 ? is that right??

Comment: Yes, that's right. `FOR /?` gives you information about handling tokens.

Comment: but how about if i need the two column (23th and 24th) data equal to 1 to output the data in 2nd column

Comment: Well I just answered what you have asked. "What ifs" can go on for ever with infinitely many answers. The expectation is you learn from the answer and extend it your self as needed, and ask new questions if required. But for this particular "what if" since it will not make answer much different from what it is, I will give a quick hint here in comment because it is not relevant to your question and editing your question with this new requirement invalidates other answers. `tokens=2,23,24` so token 2 is %%A, token 23 is %%B, token 24 is %%C : `if %%B EQU 1 if %%C EQU 1 echo %%A`

Comment: thank you so much..i already get you hint...maybe i need to ask a question using my original file so that i can get more idea on it.. thank you so much hope youll help me again nxt time

Answer (score 1):

Well you were nearly there with your powershell command, you just needed an `foreach`-loop.

This here prints out any `account` value where `columnx` is `1`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.txt" | % {Import-Csv $_.Fullname -Delimiter '|'} | Where-Object {$_.columnx -eq 1} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty account
```

Note that `%` is just an alias for `foreach` and `$_` equals each object of the loop, so every `.csv` given to it.

---

To follow up on your questions from the comment:

**What if my txt file has no header?**

`Import-Csv` has a `-Header` option which lets you add Headers for the Import, in your case it should look like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.txt" | % {Import-Csv $_.Fullname -Delimiter '|' -Header "line","account","column3","columnx"} | Where-Object {$_.columnx -eq 1} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty account
```

**What if I need the last two column to have the value "1"**

You can add additional checks to the `Where-Object` using `-and` like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.txt" | % {Import-Csv $_.Fullname -Delimiter '|'} | Where-Object {$_.columnx -eq 1 -and $_.column3 -eq 1} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty account
```

Comment: thank you for this... jsut additional question...what if my txt file dont have  a header and i need the last two  column to have the value "1" to get the output i want...

Comment: @michaeljohnperalta added an explanation for the comment question.

Also dont forget to vote up answers that helped you and to mark one of them as correct.

Answer (score 0):

as you also gave the `batch-file` tag:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%a in ('type file*.txt 2^>nul ^|findstr /e "|1"') do (
   echo %%a|findstr /x "[0-9][0-9]*"
)
```

get the second token from each line that ends with `|1` and filter it for "numbers only"

Comment: thank you very much...this is a great help but what i need is to get the data in columnx only cause in my original txt file it have 24column and more than 10 column consist of "numbers only". what should i do?

Comment: Don't understand. My code only takes the second column (`tokens=2`) and checks it for "numbers only". The code doesn't even see any other columns.

Comment: sorry if you misunderstand it what i need to know is how can i take the data in column (tokens=2) by determining the data in columnx... if data in columnx = 1 the ouput will be the data in column (tokens=2)..did i correctly explain or did i confuse you more sorry

Comment: if `columnx` is the very last column (like in your example) (no matter whether it's the 4th or the 99th), it works, because I filter for lines that end with `|1` ('findstr /e "|1"`). If it's not, @sst solution might be better.