# how to get the data of column 26 if the data in column 100 is "1"

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I have multiple txt file containing 100 column, and i want to output the data in 26th column if the corresponding data in 98th and 100th column is equal to "1".
my txt files dont have any hearder and all the data is separated by "|".

already have this code.. but no output when i run this batch file.
can someone help me debugg this and teach me thank you.

```
@echo off
for %%A in (*.txt) do for /F "usebackq tokens=26,99,100 delims=|" %%A in 
("%%~A") do ( for %%B in (%%B) and %%C in (%%C) do if %%B EQU 1  %%C EQU 1 echo %%A )
pause
```

Comment: Did you try to perform the task based upon the `PowerShell` solution you were shown in answer to your previous question? How many characters exist in your `100` fields? There is no such command/method as `for %%B in (%%B) and %%C in (%%C) do`, which you would know had you followed the advice provided in that question and read the output of `For /?`. Perhaps you're wanting to do something more like this:`For %%A In ("*.txt") Do For /F "UseBackQ Skip=1 Tokens=26,99,100 Delims=|" %%B In ("%%A") Do If "%%C"=="1" If "%%D"=="1" Echo %%B`. If your files do not have a header, do not `Skip=1`.

Comment: @compo i tried testing the powershell from my previous post but {Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.txt" | % {Import-Csv $_.Fullname -Delimiter '|' -Header "line","account","column3","columnx",.... until 100th column(RECONN?DBS)} | Where-Object {$_.RECONN/DBS -eq 1} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty can} but still no output, im using my original file while testing it i just edited the column name and put the list of all the header

Comment: @Compo i just tried the code that you said but still no output just press any key to continue

Comment: Michael, it would greatly improve your chances of a solution were potential helpers able to replicate the task. For that, we'd need to have an exact copy of at least one of the text files you're testing this with. It would also be helpful were we to know the number of lines, the length of the lines and their encoding/character sets.

Comment: You just invented a new syntax for batch script, take time to study the syntax of `FOR` and `IF` commands by typing `FOR /?` and `IF /?` at command prompt. You can't break the line anywhere you like `("%%~A") do (` must be on the same line as `FOR /F`.  And as @Compo said the there is no such thing like `and` in `FOR` and `IF` commands. atleast you've been given the correct syntax for `IF` in the comments. And I clearly mentioned in answer that if there is no header in the files remove `skip=1`. I have a feeling that you don't read carefully.

Comment: @Compo i can send you the exact copy of the text file, but how... the number of lines is from 1 to 1000 or more, what do you mean the length of the lines and their encoding/character sets??so that i can give it to you

Comment: There are limits on the number of characters which can be used in commands _(and other potential issues with file sizes/number of lines)_, this can differ depending upon the commands and how they are used, so we would ideally like to know the character count for the longest line, and preferably whether your text file is ANSI or Unicode and whether the line endings are `CRLF` (Windows style), `LF` (Unix style) or `CR` (MAC style). There are many online file sharing facilities/services available.

Comment: @sst sorry i have copy the one that i used when i put header on my file to test it and on my notepad i didnt break any of the code its still one line code..the one that i add is the "and"

Comment: Also, in order to determine if there are problems with your script, if you change `off` to `on` at line `1`, you will be able to see each command as it is run in the console window, `cmd.exe`, which should help you to debug any issues with your code.

Comment: @Compo maybe the max character per line is 8000, the text file is ANSI and the line endings is CRLF...is this good?

Comment: The maximum line length a `For /F` command can process is `8191 bytes`, _(read as characters)_, so you are very close to that maximum. All we need now is a link to download your file from a file hosting site, or to the file's content for copying/pasting in order that we can replicate what you have. If you are sure about the `ANSI`, `CRLF` then using a '`PasteBin`' type site may be your preference.

Comment: Very simple if you install GNU `awk`, it becomes `awk -F"|" "$99==1 && $100==1{print $26}" YourFile.txt`

Comment: @Compo as far as I can tell `FOR /F` has no issue reading lines with much larger number of character, but the size for each token must be less than `8191 characters`. I have tested this successfully by a file with `196,536` characters in each line containing 24 tokens, each of them with `8188` characters delimited by a single comma (8189 x 24 = 196536).

Comment: @sst: You are right. I described this point at [Maximum line length and number of tokens in FOR /F command](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7703&start=45#p51659)

Comment: @Aacini, Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /F "tokens=26 delims=|" %%a in ('type file*.txt 2>nul|findstr /e "|1|1"') do echo %%a
```

Limitations:
- [A single FOR /F command can never parse more than 31 tokens](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html), so "26" is still in range. Token 99 and 100 definitively are not.
- The `findstr /e "|1|1"` checks, if the two last columns have a value of `1` each, but doesn't care, if they are "99" and "100".
- it will not check if that 26th column is really "numbers only". If you need to check, add the `findstr /x "[0-9][0-9]*"` from my answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51906853/using-the-data-in-3-files-containing-column-x-i-need-to-output-the-data-in-colum).

Batch isn't very good for this task, you might want to choose another language.

**EDIT** I just read in a comment to your previous question, that the files may or may not have a header.  Simply checking for "numbers only" (see above) should exclude any headers. (`skip=1` is useless in this case, because it always skips the first line)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & set "$numTokens=101"

Rem/For  This is a base program that process a file via FOR /F command with up to $numTokens tokens
Rem/For  This program was created using MakeForTokens.bat application written by Antonio Perez Ayala
Rem/For  https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7703   2> NUL

Rem/For  Step 0:
Rem/For    Create an example data file
( for /L %%i in (1,1,105) do set /P "={%%i}|" ) < NUL > dataFile.txt

Rem/For  Step 1:
Rem/For    Define the series of auxiliary variables that will be used as FOR tokens.
Rem/For    The subroutine use the value of $numTokens variable as input.
call :DefineForTokens

Rem/For  Step 3:
Rem/For    Define the variable with the "delims" value that will be used in the nested FOR's.
set "delims=delims=^|"

Rem/For  Step 4:
Rem/For    Create the macro that contain the nested FOR's.
Rem/For    The subroutine use the value of $numTokens variable as input.
call :CreateNestedFors

Rem/For  Step 5:
Rem/For    This is the main FOR /F command that process the file,
for /F "usebackq tokens=1-31* %delims%" %%%$1% in ("dataFile.txt") do %NestedFors% (

   Rem/For  Step 6:
   Rem/For    Process the tokens.
   echo Token #26: %%%$26%, token #99: %%%$99%, token #100: %%%$100%

   REM To check if token #99 is "{99}" *and* token #100 is "{100}", just combine both values:
   if "%%%$99%%%%$100%" equ "{99}{100}" echo Both tokens 99 and 100 have the right values, so token #26 = %%%$26%

)

goto :EOF



:DefineForTokens

for /F "tokens=2 delims=:." %%p in ('chcp') do set /A "_cp=%%p, _pages=($numTokens/256+1)*2"
set "_hex= 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F"
call set "_pages=%%_hex:~0,%_pages%%%"
if %$numTokens% gtr 2048 echo Creating FOR tokens variables, please wait . . .
(
   echo FF FE
   for %%P in (%_pages%) do for %%A in (%_hex%) do for %%B in (%_hex%) do echo %%A%%B 3%%P 0D 00 0A 00
) > "%temp%\forTokens.hex.txt"
certutil.exe -decodehex -f "%temp%\forTokens.hex.txt" "%temp%\forTokens.utf-16le.bom.txt" >NUL
chcp 65001 >NUL
type "%temp%\forTokens.utf-16le.bom.txt" > "%temp%\forTokens.utf8.txt"
(for /L %%N in (0,1,%$numTokens%) do set /P "$%%N=")  < "%temp%\forTokens.utf8.txt" 
chcp %_cp% >NUL
del "%temp%\forTokens.*.txt"
for %%v in (_cp _hex _pages) do set "%%v="
exit /B



:CreateNestedFors

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /A "numTokens=$numTokens-1, mod=numTokens%%31, i=numTokens/31, lim=31"
if %mod% equ 0 set "mod=31"
set "NestedFors="
for /L %%i in (32,31,%numTokens%) do (
   if !i! equ 1 set "lim=!mod!"
   set "NestedFors=!NestedFors! for /F "tokens=1-!lim!* %delims%" %%!$%%i! in ("%%!$%%i!") do"
   set /A "i-=1"
)
for /F "delims=" %%a in ("!NestedFors!") do endlocal & set "NestedFors=%%a"
exit /B
```

See [Using many "tokens=..." in FOR /F command in a simple way](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7703) for a detailed description on the method used in this solution.